# PHP Login redirects but does not start the session

Tags: php, html

So I have a login page with the following code. When the correct password is entered it is supposed to start the session using `session_start(); $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;` and then redirect to home.php using `header`.

I noticed that this works but then my `home.php` checks for a started session using the code below but then redirects me back to the login page (index2.php) So clearly the session is not started... but I am not sure why.

> **I was able to fix this issue myself.** After adding `session_start();` at the top of my php pages it still made me login twice. I realized it was because I was starting the session the using `header` to redirect to `htttp://www.mysite.com/home.php` but the browser was seeing that as a new session.
>
> > **So I changed it... now it says `header("Location: home.php");` and it fixed the problem.**
>
> **TLDR: removed the `htttp://www.mysite.com` from the `header()`**

**The code for the login index.php page:**

```
 if(isset($_POST['password']))
  {
 //Connect to a database
  $host_name  = "*******.db.1and1.com";
  $database   = "db*******";
  $user_name  = "db******";
  $password   = "********.*******";

  $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
  //    echo("nice job"); 

 //Take the values from the html form and assign them to variables
    $ID = $_POST['name'];
    $userpassword = $_POST['password'];

 //Check to see if the password matches the hashes
    if (md5($userpassword) === '**********************************' 
        or md5($userpassword) === '*********************' 
        or md5($userpassword) === '***************************' 
        or md5($userpassword) === '*******************') 
  {
 //Add the visitor name to our list
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `WebsiteVisitors` (`Name`) VALUES ('$ID')") or die("Error in INSERT: ".mysqli_error($connect));
      //    echo "You have entered the correct password, congrats.";

 // Start the session so they can access other pages
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
 // Redirect them to rest of site
    header("Location: http://www.abc123.com/home.php"); 
    die();
  }

  else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Wrong Password. Check your  invitation card.\");</script>";

   } 
  }
 ?>
```

**The code on the home.php that checks for loggedin users:**

```
<?php 
 session_start();
//Check to make sure the person is loggedin
 if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true) {
//if logged in then do nothing
  } else {
//if not logged int he redirect to the login page
header("Location: http://www.abc123.com/index2.php");
 }
?>
```

Comment: Tried calling ob_start(); on the top?

Comment: Do you have any output in the `index.php` file before using `session_start()` ?

Comment: Btw. Your code is wide open for SQL-injections. `VALUES ('$ID')`. Always sanitize your inputs and preferably use prepared statements.

Comment: at `index.php`, try using `var_dump` on `$_SESSION`

Comment: also, just use `if ($_SESSION['loggedIn']==true) if you just want to check the session

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan - He needs `isset()` first, just like he wrote, otherwise he will get a "undefined index" if the session isn't set.

Comment: ops, my bad.. you're right.

Comment: try to start session at the top of the file.

Comment: @urfusion I can't start the session before a password is input, that would defeat the purpose.

Repox no I don't think so, all the php code is there for u to see, you probably now more than me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `session_start();` at top of your page right after `<?php` tag

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

// Your code

?>
```

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/function.session-start)

Comment: I don't want to start a session before a password is input. If I do, then anyone can access my other pages.

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308478/where-exactly-do-i-put-a-session-start

Comment: Hmm, that actually worked. I can login now and going straight to another page does not work (which is what I want so they cannot access without logging in).

Care to explain how this worked?

Comment: You are a blessing for me, thank you very much. I didn't quite understand what an output was, now I see that it has to be the first thing otherwise I will get those header issues I had earlier.

I am guessing it is the  `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;` that is preventing someone from going straight to another page. THANKS!

Comment: Hey, so it is still is making me login twice, so it must still not be setting               `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true` the first time.

Comment: I fixed it, it was because my headers had `http://www.example.com` so I now just have `header("Location: home.php")` and it fixed the issue