# session_start() error always redirect to login.php

Tags: php, mysql

Login (login.php) page works fine but it redirects to the `index.php` page

**login.php**

```
<?php 
 ob_start();
 session_start();  ?>   

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <form method="post" action="login.php" >
        <div class="form-group" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_pass" >
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" > 
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    include '../includes/connection.php'; /* connection query */
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];
        $userpass = $_POST['user_pass'];

        $admin_query = "select * from admin_login where user_name =  '$username' AND user_pass = '$userpass'";

        $run = mysql_query($admin_query);     
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($run);

        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
            header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('User name of password is incorrect')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

In index page (index.php), session has error and always redirects to `login.php`

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row cms-admin-panel">
     <div class="col-md-12 "><h5> Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['login_user'] ?>  </h5> <a href="logout.php">logout</a>
    <h4 align="center">CMS Admin Panel</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php } ?>
```

Logout page working fine, it redirect to the `login.php` page.

**logout.php**

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: Why you have 3 times session_start() ?

Comment: Put `session_start()` at the beginning of `login.php`.  You can't have the form or any output before. Also, `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` would show you.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works. Are you sure that you're passing something to index.php? Let's print_r($_SESSION) to look what it contains

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `session_start();` before the `<form>`.

> The session_start() function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

[Where exactly do I put a SESSION_START?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308478/where-exactly-do-i-put-a-session-start)

**Long answer:**

Since sessions are handles by cookies by default,

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Hi blackpla9ue,  session_start(); I put top of the page, but sill redirect to login.php. I have post latest code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your session_start() should be at the very top of the page.
Secondly, if you ever have some kind of situation where you have more than one session_start() in a page, always check if session is started already or not as,

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
   session_start();
}
```

Third reason, if header are already sent or some kind of session cache limiter error, you can fix that by output buffer started at the top of page as

```
ob_start();
```