# Session Markup Issue

Tags: php, session

This top is already created and i have looked at almost all of them but i am still having this issue. The problem i am having is when I try to login to my admin panel everything flows great until i get to the admin dashboard page where it kicks me back to login. I have tried everything and i have one answer. It myself think that for some reason its to saying that i have made a session. My code for login_process.php and dashboard.php are:

login_process.php (Starts the session here. I get no incorrect details error!)

```
<?php

include '../includes/settings.php';
include '../includes/mysql.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_hashed = md5($email . $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password_hashed'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    Header("Location: {$website_domain}/admin/login?s=1");

} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
    Header("Location: {$website_domain}/admin/dashboard");
}
?>
```

dashboard.php (header.php has session_start(); so i don't have to re-add that =)

```
<?php


if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    header("Location: {$website_domain}/admin/login");
}
require_once('assets/header.php');
?>

 <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Dashboard
        <small>Control panel</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>150</h3>

              <p>New Orders</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-green">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>53<sup style="font-size: 20px">%</sup></h3>

              <p>Bounce Rate</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>44</h3>

              <p>User Registrations</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-red">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>65</h3>

              <p>Unique Visitors</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
      <!-- Main row -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Left col -->
        <section class="col-lg-7 connectedSortable">
          <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
          <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
            <!-- Tabs within a box -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab">Area</a></li>
              <li><a href="#sales-chart" data-toggle="tab">Donut</a></li>
              <li class="pull-left header"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i> Sales</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content no-padding">
              <!-- Morris chart - Sales -->
              <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
              <div class="chart tab-pane" id="sales-chart" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.nav-tabs-custom -->

          <!-- Chat box -->
          <div class="box box-success">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">Chat</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Status">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="btn-toggle">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm active"><i class="fa fa-square text-green"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-square text-red"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body chat" id="chat-box">
              <!-- chat item -->
              <div class="item">
                <img src="dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" alt="user image" class="online">

                <p class="message">
                  <a href="#" class="name">
                    <small class="text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2:15</small>
                    Mike Doe
                  </a>
                  I would like to meet you to discuss the latest news about
                  the arrival of the new theme. They say it is going to be one the
                  best themes on the market
                </p>
                <div class="attachment">
                  <h4>Attachments:</h4>

                  <p class="filename">
                    Theme-thumbnail-image.jpg
                  </p>

                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-flat">Open</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.attachment -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.item -->
              <!-- chat item -->
              <div class="item">
                <img src="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="user image" class="offline">

                <p class="message">
                  <a href="#" class="name">
                    <small class="text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5:15</small>
                    Alexander Pierce
                  </a>
                  I would like to meet you to discuss the latest news about
                  the arrival of the new theme. They say it is going to be one the
                  best themes on the market
                </p>
              </div>
              <!-- /.item -->
              <!-- chat item -->
              <div class="item">
                <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="user image" class="offline">

                <p class="message">
                  <a href="#" class="name">
                    <small class="text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5:30</small>
                    Susan Doe
                  </a>
                  I would like to meet you to discuss the latest news about
                  the arrival of the new theme. They say it is going to be one the
                  best themes on the market
                </p>
              </div>
              <!-- /.item -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.chat -->
            <div class="box-footer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Type message...">

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box (chat box) -->

          <!-- TO DO List -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="ion ion-clipboard"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">To Do List</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <ul class="pagination pagination-sm inline">
                  <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <ul class="todo-list">
                <li>
                  <!-- drag handle -->
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <!-- checkbox -->
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <!-- todo text -->
                  <span class="text">Design a nice theme</span>
                  <!-- Emphasis label -->
                  <small class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 mins</small>
                  <!-- General tools such as edit or delete-->
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Make the theme responsive</span>
                  <small class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 4 hours</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
                  <small class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 day</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
                  <small class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 days</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Check your messages and notifications</span>
                  <small class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 week</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="handle">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                      </span>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="">
                  <span class="text">Let theme shine like a star</span>
                  <small class="label label-default"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 month</small>
                  <div class="tools">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer clearfix no-border">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->

          <!-- quick email widget -->
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">Quick Email</h3>
              <!-- tools box -->
              <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                  <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
              <!-- /. tools -->
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailto" placeholder="Email to:">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Message" style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer clearfix">
              <button type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-default" id="sendEmail">Send
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </section>
        <!-- /.Left col -->
        <!-- right col (We are only adding the ID to make the widgets sortable)-->
        <section class="col-lg-5 connectedSortable">

          <!-- Map box -->
          <div class="box box-solid bg-light-blue-gradient">
            <div class="box-header">
              <!-- tools box -->
              <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm daterange pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Date range">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse" style="margin-right: 5px;">
                  <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
              </div>
              <!-- /. tools -->

              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">
                Visitors
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <div id="world-map" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body-->
            <div class="box-footer no-border">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4">
                  <div id="sparkline-1"></div>
                  <div class="knob-label">Visitors</div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4">
                  <div id="sparkline-2"></div>
                  <div class="knob-label">Online</div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                  <div id="sparkline-3"></div>
                  <div class="knob-label">Exists</div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->

          <!-- solid sales graph -->
          <div class="box box-solid bg-teal-gradient">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="fa fa-th"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">Sales Graph</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn bg-teal btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn bg-teal btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body border-radius-none">
              <div class="chart" id="line-chart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer no-border">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4">
                  <input type="text" class="knob" data-readonly="true" value="20" data-width="60" data-height="60" data-fgColor="#39CCCC">

                  <div class="knob-label">Mail-Orders</div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4">
                  <input type="text" class="knob" data-readonly="true" value="50" data-width="60" data-height="60" data-fgColor="#39CCCC">

                  <div class="knob-label">Online</div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                  <input type="text" class="knob" data-readonly="true" value="30" data-width="60" data-height="60" data-fgColor="#39CCCC">

                  <div class="knob-label">In-Store</div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-footer -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->

          <!-- Calendar -->
          <div class="box box-solid bg-green-gradient">
            <div class="box-header">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>

              <h3 class="box-title">Calendar</h3>
              <!-- tools box -->
              <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                <!-- button with a dropdown -->
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Add new event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clear events</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">View calendar</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <!-- /. tools -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
              <!--The calendar -->
              <div id="calendar" style="width: 100%"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer text-black">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <!-- Progress bars -->
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #1</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">90%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 90%;"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #2</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">70%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 70%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #3</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">60%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 60%;"></div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="clearfix">
                    <span class="pull-left">Task #4</span>
                    <small class="pull-right">40%</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress xs">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 40%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->

        </section>
        <!-- right col -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row (main row) -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <?php
  require_once('assets/footer.php');
  ?>
```

I would appreciate all help to this issue. Hopefully this does not get deleted because i have searched the whole site trying diff things but nothing on here helped so i thought i would post. Once again, i appreciate all help!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: I am only using MD5 for the time being. I am just now learning to code and i am just making the basic login before i go through everything and make it secure. Any help on why this isn't working tho?

Comment: _"header.php has session_start(); so i don't have to re-add that"_ - well you are checking `if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {` __before__ you embed the header.php, how do you expect that to work out? // Put session_start at the very top of all of your scripts. Period. Don't argue. Apart from some including, do not execute anything else before you have not started the session. (There might be reasons to only start a  session under specific circumstance - but on your beginner level, you should not worry about those.)

Comment: _"before i go through everything and make it secure."_ This is a bad way to build software. You think you'll go back later to fix it, but that doesn't happen in the real world. Get into the habit of doing it the right way from the start. It doesn't take any more effort to type `password_hash()` than it does to type `md5()`.

Comment: This is my first project. I am just learning lo. I appreciate the note tho. I am not planning on using this in reality. This is a learning project. I appreciate the help tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session_start(); must be on the top:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

You move require_once('assets/header.php'); up and take care that session_start(); is on the top.
For more details look at [Where exactly do I put a SESSION_START?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308478/where-exactly-do-i-put-a-session-start)