# Is there a way to show errors on the form itself but the form action redirects to another php file?

Tags: php

I want to show an error to my login page if username & password doesn't match considering my action form redirects to another php file.

tried setting $_SESSION and echoed it to my login page, the echo keeps coming back after refreshing.

login page:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">

        <label>Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
        <label><?php echo $_SESSION['valid']; ?></label>
</form>
```

test.php:

```
session_start();

$uname = "user";
$pass = "123";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {



    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(($username == $uname) && ($password == $pass)) {
        $_SESSION['valid'] = "success";
        header('Location: success.php');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['valid'] = "fail";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

i expect "Username or password is incorrect" below the submit button form.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `session` is `set` or `not` in your login page like below :

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">

        <label>Username: </label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
        <label><?php 
       ///checking if session is set then print 
         if($_SESSION['valid']!=null && isset($_SESSION['valid'])){
            echo $_SESSION['valid']; 
         }
        ?></label>
</form>
```

Comment: hi this is what i'm looking for but there's an error "Notice: Undefined index: valid". if i set $_SESSION['valid] = "" on the login page.then it will just keep $_SESSION['valid'] empty what should i do?

Comment: did you add `session_start();` at top of your login page?

Comment: yes if i won't click the submit button the error is there.

Comment: solved it by replacing this line <label><?php echo $_SESSION['valid']; ?></label>
 of code on the login page by this https://pastebin.com/HZds8frm

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you have to put `session_start()` at the first line of every file where you want to use the session, even HTML pages. Maybe you haven't included in your login page ? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308478/where-exactly-do-i-put-a-session-start) if you want to understand why.